# javascript - how to stop execution of a recursive function after a certain time

Tags: javascript, multithreading, recursion

I'm working on a sudoku game, and one of my functions is a recursive function that checks the number of possible solutions for the puzzle. This function works fast at 95% of the time, but the user can make a puzzle in which this function need some seconds to finish execution, so all that I want that if the execution of this function lasts more than 300ms, it execute and give me the partial result.
to demonstrate, Lets say I have this simple recursive function which enters an infinite loop:

```
function inf(){
    console.log("a");
    inf();
```

I want to stop its execution after 300ms.
here's what I tried to do, I initialized a global var called `timer` which equals 0, and I called a new function which suppose to do the job for me, here it is:

```
function stopExec(){
    t = setTimeout(() => { timer = 1 }, 300);
    newInf();
```

as `newInf()` is the updated function of `inf()`:

```
function newInf(){
    if(timer == 1)
        return 0;
    console.log("a");
    inf();
```

The problem is that when `newInf()` starts running, the setTimeOut call `t` does never execute.

Comment: Could you set a global to the time you want to terminate (i.e. current time at start + 300ms), then have each call to `inf` check it?

Comment: @ScottHunter it worked, thanks :)